# click dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make clickable dropdown but it doesn't work. This is my code, I saw this code from another question i did everything and still not working. Can someone help?

HTML CODE:

```
<li class = "mobmeni">
  <div class = "mobmenidiv">
    <button id="kopceddown" class="mobmenikopce"></button>
  </div>
</li>

<div id = "mobddown">
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a></li>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
    function show_or_hide()
    {
      if(getElementById("mobddown").style.display="none")
        getElementById("mobddown").style.display="block";
      else 
        getElementById("mobddown").style.display="none";
    }

    getElementById("kopceddown").addEventListener("click", show_or_hide);
```

CSS:

```
#mobddown{
    font-size: 2em;
    display: none;
}

#mobddown li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
}

#mobddown li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#mobddown li:hover{
    background-color: #35aa96;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console? Also you're missing `document` in front of `getElementById("kopceddown")`

Comment: Your `<li>` elements should really be inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: Check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in your if statement needs to use the equality comparison operator `===`,  not the assignment operator `=`.

So it should be `getElementById("mobddown").style.display === "none"`

...and not `getElementById("mobddown").style.display = "none"`.

Also, you should be using `document.getElementById()`, and your `<li>` elements should be inside a list element (`<ul>` or `<ol>`).

Here is a snippet of your code working:

```js
function show_or_hide() {
  if (document.getElementById("mobddown").style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("mobddown").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mobddown").style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.getElementById("kopceddown").addEventListener("click", show_or_hide);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="mobmeni">
    <div class="mobmenidiv">
      <button id="kopceddown" class="mobmenikopce"></button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="mobddown" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Берово</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OK, It works now but when i load it first i need to click 2 times and then it will start working

Comment: You need to set the style attribute on your mobddown element, i.e. `<ul id="mobddown" style="display: none;">`, and not in the CSS.

This is because when you access an element's style property in javascript, you're accessing the element's inline style attribute. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Answer (score 4):

It may be better just to use a simple `<select>` tag:

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**You may add css to this later if you like.**

Comment: It is a lot easier without js

Comment: Wrong.. the reason to use `li` over regular dropdown is to have uniform UI in all browsers ...

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Its not wrong, it's just another method in which to do it.

Answer (score 0):

use `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` alternatively.

example:

```
function show_or_hide()
{
   if(document.getElementById("mobddown").getAttribute('style')=='display:none') 
       document.getElementById('mobddown').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
   else document.getElementById("mobddown").setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need 'document' before getElementById

```
document.getElementById(id);
```

Then you have to use '===' in the `if` condition

```
function show_or_hide()
    {
      var ddown = document.getElementById("mobddown");
      if(ddown.style.display === "block")
        ddown.style.display = "none";
      else 
        ddown.style.display = "block";
    }

document.getElementById("kopceddown").addEventListener("click", show_or_hide);
```

[Here's working example](https://jsfiddle.net/f4couh2f/1/)

Comment: I'd argue the use of the triple equals comparison operator `===`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/6008014